# Changing a variable used in a class?

Tags: python, global-variables, static-variables

I'm using a variable as part of a string within a class, however printing the string shows what the variable had been set to at the start of the program, rather than what it's been changed to

My current code basically says this:

```
b = 0
class addition:
    a = 1 + b

def enter():
    global b;
    b = input("Enter a number: ")
    print(addition.a) - Prints "1" regardless of what is typed in
enter()
```

How would I "rerun" the class to use the value assigned to the variable in the function?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: sorry, that 'c' in input was meant to be a 'b'. I've fixed it. I'm attempting to output the user's input + 1.

Comment: `a = 1+b` is evaluated when the class is defined, so `a` is and will remain `1`, regardless of what `b` might become later.

Comment: Is there any way to re-evaluate the class in a function? Or create a local instance of the string 'a' in a function using something like "newvar = addition.a" then evaluating newvar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to use the reassigned value of b is creating classmethod `a`:

```
b = 0
class addition:
    @classmethod
    def a(cls):
        return 1 + b

def enter():
    global b;
    b = int(input("Enter a number: ")) # convert string input to int
    print(addition.a()) # calling a with ()
enter()
```

But it breaks your original semantics to call `addition.a` without `()`. If you really need to save it, there is a way using metaclass:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == 'a':
            return 1 + b
        return object.__getattr__(self, name)

b = 0
class addition(metaclass=Meta):
    pass

def enter():
    global b;
    b = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    print(addition.a) # calling a without ()
enter()
```

Comment: I'm not too set on using the variable without brackets, plus meta classes' might as well be greek to me at this point. Thanks! The first method worked

Comment: Glad to help you. Yes, metaclasses are too complicated in most cases. [If you wonder whether you need them, you don’t](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/12/01/a-primer-on-python-metaclasses/#Conclusion:-When-Should-You-Use-Metaclasses?)